# boost 1.73 messages reporting during project build

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm using Boost 1.73 on a older project which was using Boost 1.48.  My intention is to fix any warnings and errors along the way.

When compiling the project I'm getting some odd messages which are not in the source of the project but in boost itself, these messages are like most error messages, cryptic and not terribly helpful.

```
1>debugengine.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\utility(173): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from '_Ty' to '_Ty2', possible loss of data
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty2=unsigned short
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(111): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const char(&)[4],int,0>(_Other1,_Other2 &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=unsigned short,
1>            _Other1=const char (&)[4],
1>            _Other2=int
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(99): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const char(&)[4],int,0>(_Other1,_Other2 &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=unsigned short,
1>            _Other1=const char (&)[4],
1>            _Other2=int
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(168): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<month_type>(const std::string &)' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\gregorian\parsers.hpp(49): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'date_type boost::date_time::parse_date<boost::gregorian::date>(const std::string &,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            date_type=boost::gregorian::date
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(54): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<9>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(53): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<8>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(52): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<7>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(51): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<6>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(50): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<5>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(49): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<4>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(48): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<3>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(47): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<2>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\bind\placeholders.hpp(46): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::arg<1>' being compiled
```

Is there anything I can do?

I'm using MSVC 2017.

I've narrowed the problem down to just one file and commented out everything except:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
```

This is what I get when compiling just this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Debug Service Group, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>debugengine.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\utility(173): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from '_Ty' to '_Ty2', possible loss of data
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty2=unsigned short
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(111): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const char(&)[4],int,0>(_Other1,_Other2 &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=unsigned short,
1>            _Other1=const char (&)[4],
1>            _Other2=int
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(99): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<const char(&)[4],int,0>(_Other1,_Other2 &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=unsigned short,
1>            _Other1=const char (&)[4],
1>            _Other2=int
1>        ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp(168): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<month_type>(const std::string &)' being compiled
1>c:\boost\boost_1_73_0\boost\date_time\gregorian\parsers.hpp(49): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'date_type boost::date_time::parse_date<boost::gregorian::date>(const std::string &,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            date_type=boost::gregorian::date
1>        ]
1>Done building project "Debug Service Group.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is that the last message? Seems you've truncated a sequence of messages concerning a template instantiation. The source of the errors will be the last message.

Comment: @john, I'm just about to edit the post because I've found something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings are harmless. Here's the source in boost\date_time\date_parsing.hpp line 99

```
    static std::map<std::string, unsigned short> month_map =
      { { "jan", 1 },  { "january", 1 },
```

As you can see the value type of the map is `unsigned short` but it is being initialised with `int` values.

I'm slightly surprised at the warning, you might think that MSVC 2017 would be smart enough to realise that assigning `1` to an `unsigned short` is not a problem.

I don't get any warnings with MSVC 2019

Comment: Thank you, why haven't the developers put in a cast to unsigned short just to prevent the warning?

Comment: @SPlatten You would have to ask the developers that. Maybe they only test with the latest version of each compiler? Remember these guys are volunteers and there is only so much time available

Comment: Maybe its just me, I could never release anything that compiles with warnings.